# Add one object to M2M fields of many objects in a bulk transaction

Tags: django

I've got the following `post_save` signal.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Questionnaire)
def add_new_eligible_users_to_questionnaire(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.open_to_all:
            users = Respondent.objects.filter(organization=instance.organization)
            users.update(eligible_for=instance)
```

The idea is that once the survey is created, if it is open to everyone, it will automatically be added to their `eligible_for` row.

Unfortunately, `update()` doesn't work on M2M relationships. Is there any way I can do this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following model:

```
class Respondent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('Home.ListenUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    eligible_for = models.ManyToManyField('Questionnaire', related_name='eligible_users', null=True)
```

I used this to accomplish it:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Questionnaire)
def add_new_eligible_users_to_questionnaire(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.open_to_all:
            users = Respondent.objects.filter(organization=instance.organization)
            instance.eligible_users.set(users)
```